# What is the C# analog of this VBScript code that checks the Active Directory password expiration?

Tags: c#, vbscript, active-directory, passwords, user-accounts

I have the following VBScript script that checks the password expiration of an Active Directory user account. Could someone please help me convert this code to C#? Thanks a lot.

```
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
Const E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND  = &h8000500D
Const ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND    = .000000100
Const SECONDS_IN_DAY            = 86400

Set objADSystemInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")              ' LINE 8
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objADSystemInfo.UserName)   ' LINE 9

intUserAccountControl = objUser.Get("userAccountControl")
If intUserAccountControl And ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
    WScript.Echo "The password does not expire."
    WScript.Quit
Else
    dtmValue = objUser.PasswordLastChanged
    If Err.Number = E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND Then
        WScript.Echo "The password has never been set."
        WScript.Quit
    Else
        intTimeInterval = Int(Now - dtmValue)
        WScript.Echo "The password was last set on " & _
          DateValue(dtmValue) & " at " & TimeValue(dtmValue)  & vbCrLf & _
          "The difference between when the password was last" & vbCrLf & _
          "set and today is " & intTimeInterval & " days"
    End If

    Set objDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & objADSystemInfo.DomainDNSName)
    Set objMaxPwdAge = objDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")

    If objMaxPwdAge.LowPart = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "The Maximum Password Age is set to 0 in the " & _
                     "domain. Therefore, the password does not expire."
        WScript.Quit
    Else
        dblMaxPwdNano = _
            Abs(objMaxPwdAge.HighPart * 2^32 + objMaxPwdAge.LowPart)
        dblMaxPwdSecs = dblMaxPwdNano * ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND
        dblMaxPwdDays = Int(dblMaxPwdSecs / SECONDS_IN_DAY)
        WScript.Echo "Maximum password age is " & dblMaxPwdDays & " days"

        If intTimeInterval >= dblMaxPwdDays Then
            WScript.Echo "The password has expired."
        Else
            WScript.Echo "The password will expire on " & _
              DateValue(dtmValue + dblMaxPwdDays) & " (" & _
              Int((dtmValue + dblMaxPwdDays) - Now) & " days from today)."
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look on the scripts from this book:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788236.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an app that warned users better about their expiring passwords.  They hated the Windows warnings in the XenApp environment.  Here's the method I wrote that handles the expiration check.

```
    public static bool WarnUser(int passwordValidityPeriod, int passwordExpirationWarningPeriod, out int daysUntilExpiration)
    {
        TimeSpan due;
        bool result = false;
        TimeSpan pwdExpirationWarningPeriod = new TimeSpan(passwordExpirationWarningPeriod, 0, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan pwdValidityPeriod = new TimeSpan(passwordValidityPeriod, 0, 0, 0);
        DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://DC=YOUR_DOMAIN,DC=com");
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
        search.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", Environment.UserName);
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");
        SearchResult sr = search.FindOne();
        UserAccountControl uac = (UserAccountControl)sr.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];
        var pwdLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTime(long.Parse(sr.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0].ToString()));
        TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now.Subtract(pwdLastSet);
        due = pwdValidityPeriod - difference;
        //Check for non expiring passwords and do nothing when one is encountered.
        if (!uac.HasFlag(UserAccountControl.DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD))
        {
            if ((pwdValidityPeriod - difference) <= pwdExpirationWarningPeriod)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        daysUntilExpiration = ((int)due.TotalDays < 0) ? 0 : (int)due.TotalDays;
        return result;
    }
}
```